# Limit my ticker count to maximum 12 Months

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, case

I'm trying to write a case expression where it looks at the due date and if it has passed chooses the upcoming or closest due date. Now due to certain database restriction I have to do this manually. Problem is my code is comparing the extracted day **(a)** from the *due_date* with extracted day **(b)** from *current time_stamp* and if a < b that means due date for current month has passed and the next one would be ( a / current month + 1) <- Date format Example a / Oct.

Now the problem is if current month is 12 (Dec) that would make the next due date **a / 13** which I do not want. Any way to limit it to 12 and reset to 1?

Also, bonus points if you can help me the year part?

```
due_date   |current_timestamp | Result
----------- -----------------  -----------
2021-12-05 |2022-10-18        |  2022-11-05
2022-06-02 |2022-10-18        |  2022-11-02
2022-10-19 |2022-10-18        |  2022-10-19
2022-10-15 |2022-10-18        |  2022-11-15
2021-10-20 |2022-10-18        |  2022-10-20
```

```
CASE 
  WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM due_date ) < EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM due_date ),'/',(EXTRACT(Month FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))+1)
  ELSE CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM due_date ),'/',(EXTRACT(Month FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
END AS "Next Payment Date"
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and a clear example of your expected result?  And you've tried `due_date + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'`?

Comment: This wouldn't work since my due date can be of last year that is why I'm extracting the day and comparing it since the day remains static throughout only the month part needs updating - I've added sample data and expected result.

Comment: Try using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > (due_date + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'`. If that is true, then it's past due, and it takes year-end boundaries into account.

Comment: @bbaird why did you remove three columns?  They had good explanatory powers.

Comment: Yea not sure if removing was a great idea - I don;t think Ron yours would work since I want to check if the date is past - use that day and get the next month! My current code works except when the current month is Dec it'll go till 12 when we +1 that is my main issue!

Comment: My method *does* do what you want.  "IF current_timestamp > (due_date + 1 month) THEN it's past due."

Comment: I want the next closest due date if its passed then the next months date else month remains the same (current) month with the due DAY not sure if you understand the question. You're assuming due_date is one month prior- It's NOT it can be last year as-well. That columns is essentially only good for DAY value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to remember that most databases have tools that handle date addition/subtraction/comparison.  For Postgres, you can find them here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

I don't think the year boundary is what is going to give you a headache - months can have different numbers of days and we can't just increment the value of month by 1 and still receive a valid date.  To get around this limitation we use `INTERVAL` in Postgres (and some other SQL variants as well):

```
> SELECT DATE'2022-01-30' + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'

> 2022-02-28
```

This should get you what you want from what I've been able to understand.  If there needs to be a modification, please let me know:

```
CASE
    /* If due date is in future */
    WHEN Due_Date > Current_Timestamp THEN Due_Date
    /* Past due date of current month */
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Due_Date) <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM Current_Timestamp) THEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp)::DATE + EXTRACT(DAY FROM Due_Date)::INT -1 + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
    /* Day of due date does not exceed last day of current month */
    WHEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp)::DATE + EXTRACT(DAY FROM Due_Date)::INT - 1 < DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') THEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp)::DATE + EXTRACT(DAY FROM Due_Date)::INT - 1
    /* Day of due date exceeds last day of month and current date is not last day of month */
    WHEN Current_Timestamp::DATE + 1 < DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') THEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')::DATE - 1
    /* Day of due date exceeds last day of month and current date is last day of month */
    ELSE DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',Current_Timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')::DATE + EXTRACT(DAY FROM Due_Date)::INT - 1
  END
```

The last condition works because "short" months (Feb, April, June, September, November) are always preceded/followed by months with 31 days.

See Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6061

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Only edit I had to make was on the 2nd last condition (Current_Timestamp::DATE)+1..

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, it's better to to use calendar functions as much as
possible instead of computing the year-month-day parts separately.

You didn't mention whether the day of a due date can be a 31/30/29, and then what should be the result when the current month doesn't have such a day. Some billing systems solve that problem by never using such dates (typically, they're pushing the date to the 1st of the next month). Let's assume that's your case.

The two dates you need to compute are:

- the same day as the due date but in the current month:

```
 date_trunc('month', current_date) + '1 day'::interval * (extract(day from due_date)-1)
```

- the same day as the due date but in the next month from now (to be used when that day is already in the past in this month):

```
 date_trunc('month', current_date) + '1 day'::interval * (extract(day from due_date)-1)
 + '1 month'::interval
```

With these, you just have select one of the dates depending on the case:

```
with list(due_date) as (values
('2021-12-05'::date),
('2022-06-02'),
('2022-10-19'),
('2022-10-15'),
('2021-10-20'))
,

list2 AS (select due_date,
  date_trunc('month', current_date) +
    '1 day'::interval * (extract(day from due_date)-1) AS same_day_this_month
   FROM list
)
select due_date,
 case
  when due_date > current_date then due_date
  when same_day_this_month > current_date then same_day_this_month
  else same_day_this_month + '1 month'::interval
  end
from list2;
```

Result:

```
  due_date  |          case          
------------+------------------------
 2021-12-05 | 2022-11-05 00:00:00+01
 2022-06-02 | 2022-11-02 00:00:00+01
 2022-10-19 | 2022-10-19 00:00:00+02
 2022-10-15 | 2022-11-15 00:00:00+01
 2021-10-20 | 2022-10-20 00:00:00+02
```

Comment: Thanks very much super helpful.